# c# Unit test for importing database using smo and checking sql connection

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, smo, unit-testing

How can I implement a unit test for database transfer from remote server into localhost using smo.
Also is it possible to test the sql connection?
I don't have so much experience in Moq , NUnit. Any recommendations are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a better suited question for [StackOverflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com) but **NUnit** is a pretty standard and easy to use **Unit Testing** framework. You can follow this guide by Microsoft on [**Testing with NUnit**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-nunit).

Testing that the connection string for the server is valid and the server is online make for good **Unit Tests**, also doing some mock schema changes to your **Source Database**, running your **SMO** process, and testing the changes are replicated on the **Target Database** is a good **Unit Test**.

Ideally you should have a **Unit Test** for each piece of your database you want replicated from **Source** to **Target**, e.g. the Table schema, the data, indexes, constraints (primary keys, foreign keys), database properties and extended properties, etc.

Comment: Testing a server is online is integration testing, not unit testing.

Comment: @Charlieface Hi again ;). I respectfully disagree. **Integration Testing** is ["*Integration testing is the phase in software testing in which individual software modules are combined and tested as a group*"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing). Individually testing if a server is online in an isolated single test is a valid **Unit Test**, as it is a specific single thing being tested (independent of the integration of multiple pieces of software).